# Which is the best way to redirect 2 different users to 2 different Activities after they login using their email and password?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm creating an application with 2 different users.
The first one is the student and the second one is the professor/teacher.
Which is the best way to redirect them to a different Activity after they login using their email and password?
All the students who will login will redirect in a different Activity from the teacher or professor.

Comment: You'd better use 2 different Fragments on the same Activity.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a shared preference object  `SharedPreferences preferences;`

then define two boolean variables:

```
private static String STUDENT_LOG_IN_STATUS = "student_log_in_status";
private static String TEACHER_LOG_IN_STATUS = "teacher_log_in_status";
```

then create setter and getter for each variable like that:

```
public void setLogInStatus(boolean status) {
        preferences.edit().putBoolean(STUDENT_LOG_IN_STATUS, status).apply();
    }

public boolean getLogInStatus() {
        return preferences.getBoolean(STUDENT_LOG_IN_STATUS, false);
    }
```

and the same for TEACHER_LOG_IN_STATUS .

if the student or teacher logged in successfully set his login status to true if he logged out set the login status to false.

and check for these status every time you the app starts if any one of them is true redirect the user to the right screen based on his type if both of them are false open log in screen

Comment: the problem is what if i register in a device and i login to it then i logout . then i login my account in another device . i think it will error or will not login. correct me if i'm wrong .

Comment: no when you login in in one device the app save user data in 'sharedprefrences'  if when logout set these data to the default value so the login data will be updated at each device separately

Answer (score -1):

Store some boolean value with each account that says "isTeacher" (for example)

Make an if-else statement around the call to start another activity to check said value

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like or how you authenticate your users...  Do you have some type of database? If not, how do you define a teacher vs a student? If your code can tell the difference, then I don't think I need to teach how to write an if-else statement in Java